# wget not downloading pdfs in directories

Tags: pdf, wget

Following problem: I'm trying to download a directory that contains pdfs, and it downloads the file structure, some of the pdfs but doesn't go deeper than the 2nd directory to download pdfs.

Details (theoretical)

So I have folder1/folder2/folder3(/folder4/folder5)

*folder1* contains no pdfs, file structure contained in it, is downloaded.

*folder 2* contains another folder and some pdfs, folders are created, pdfs are downloaded

*folder 3* sometimes contains more folders, which are created but all pdfs contained in it and in the subfolders are not downloaded.

here is what I'm using to try to download all of it:

```
wget -r -l inf --no-remove-listing -np -c -w 3 --no-check-certificate -R "index.html*" -P "target directory" "https://etc./"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: -erobots=off was the solution. Which is weird since the site actually a wget command that I disagreed with, but still tried and had even less of an result than with my own commands, anyway -erobots=off was not mentioned in their orignally code so I figured and I didn't need it, but I did.